# How to delete specific product images from Magento 2 database and physical images from folder?

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images

Deleting selected product / SKU images from Magento 2 database and the physical images files from the media product catalog folders which are dynamically created by Magento during image upload.

1. Locate the image and image physical path. In the database, the images and the physical path reference of the images are stores in the below 3 tables

- **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery**
  *//This is where the physical
  image path is stored*
- **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value**
  *//This table has the storeid, valueid, product entity id and the
  position of the images*
- **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity** *//This table is
  where the mapping between the product entity id and valueid mapping
  done.*
- **And the images are stored physically under magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product/x/x/x**

2. First step is to identify the physical path of the server and delete from the media --> catalog --> product path, I used the below query to create a file with remove command and the image physical path on the server.

This example was executed on Ubuntu 16.04, the below commands and sql querie. Will run on any Linux distro and Mysql.

Basically create a file with the below command to delete the images,

> run the below query on the command prompt.

```
 - mysql -u username -p databasename -e "select concat('rm -f
   /home/magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product',value) from
   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery  where value_id in (select
   value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
   where entity_id in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity
   where sku in ('SKU1','SKU2','SKU3'))) and attribute_id=90;" >
   imagefilestodelete.sh
```

In my case, Magento is installed in folder /home/magento2rootpath - replace with your actual magento root path and replace SKU1, SKU2, SKU3 with your actual product SKU

Output of the generated file imagefilestodelete.sh

```
rm -f /home/magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product/4/m/4m6a6330.jpg
rm -f /home/magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product/4/m/4m6a6332.jpg
rm -f /home/magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product/4/m/4m6a6333.jpg
rm -f /home/magento2rootpath/pub/media/catalog/product/4/m/4m6a6335.jpg
```

From the CLI run the below command

> sh imagefilestodelete.sh

Now that we have deleted the physical image files from the media catalog respective image path folder, we will now need to remove the same from database, I used the below sql queries in the same order to remove the file references from database.

3. Remove the image references from the respective tables in Magento

> Login to your mysql with user having privilege to execute delete
> queries

```
 - delete from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where value_id in
   (select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity where entity_id
   in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku in
   ('SKU1','SKU2','SKU3'))) and attribute_id=90;

 - delete from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
   where entity_id in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity
   where sku in ('SKU1','SKU2','SKU3'));

 - delete from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value where
   entity_id in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku
   in ('SKU1','SKU2','SKU3'));
```

NOTE: Before you execute the above delete queries, run SELECT to check the entries. To do that replace delete from above queries to `SELECT *`

This way it was easier for me to delete images for specific products on production and not truncate the entire tables.